# JS - Post current quote to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

**Here is what I'm aiming for -**

When a user clicks 'Facebook' button - I'd like the text highlighted in green here:
URL - cl.ly/TlH6 - to post to their profile.

Here is the site - http://afrifacti.com

**Here is what I have so far:**

1 - Signed into my *main* facebook account -  but it doesn't have the quote - the URL=>cl.ly/Tkjj

2 - Signed into my *tester* facebook account - it doesn't post anything - the URL=> cl.ly/TkhL

Any thoughts on why it would work with one and not the other?

Any help would be appreciated here is the code:

```
<script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/quotes.js"></script>
  <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    // facebook setup
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({ appId: '665401243510103', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
      FB.getLoginStatus();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    var quote = null;
    (function showRandomQuote() {
      var randomQuoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
      quote = quotes[randomQuoteIndex];

      $("#raw-quote").text(quote.rawQuote);
      $("#date").text(quote.date);
      $("#author").text(quote.citation);
      $("#date").text(quote.date);
      $("#link")
        .attr("href", quote.link)
        .attr("title", quote.altText)
        .text(quote.linkText);

    })();

    (function setupFacebookButton () {
      $("#facebook-button").click(function() {
        FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name: quote.date + " quote of the day",
          link: 'http://www.afrifacti.com/',
          caption: quote.altText,
          description: "the description",
          message: quote.rawQuote
        });
      });

    })();

  </script>
```

-
Ry

Answer (score 0):

I visited the site and saw "an error occured" when I clicked the FB button. A common reason for this to fail is that your app is in Sandbox mode, which means only developers on the project can access it.

As for the quote not showing up, try putting a `"testing testing 123"` type string in for `message` to see if that shows up in your feed box. If not then there may be a problem with `quotes` being defined inside `showRandomQuote()`

Comment: Thanks Pat,the app was definitely in sandbox mode. For the second issue, should it look like --> message: "testing testing 123" right? I  tried that and it still had the empty post box with no quote.

Comment: Yep `message` has been removed. Here's the doc with all the available options: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/